# Create ERD type diagrams from Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, diagram, erd

I'm beginning to learn Ruby on Rails, and looking at other peoples code.  Is there any way to take an exisiting codebase and create object relationship diagrams or Entity relationship diagrams (ERD's) ?

I know Visio can do some things given a database, but I was hoping to produce diagrams of classes and objects.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may want to check out [Railroad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/). It takes your Rails project and visualizes it. It can create diagrams based off of your models (based off of has_many, has_and_belongs_to_many, etc), controllers (based on inheritance hierarchy) and state machine diagrams, which I have never used.

But it is pretty cool and does what it is supposed to. It may not have all the flair that Visio has but it is a darn good solution.

Comment: Railroad didn't work for me with Rails 3, there is however this plugin which works fine: http://github.com/voormedia/rails-erd

Comment: I wish I could upvote rdvddijk's comment - Railroad is pretty old now. Rails ERD however takes only seconds to install and works great.

Comment: As Railroad is not working with ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.10 you can use Railroady instead as I learned in this other SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624457/railroad-is-not-working-giving-me-issues-ie-railroad-0-5-0-lib-railroad-app-di

Answer (score 25):

Also **[Rails ERD](http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/) is not bad**. It is a bit simpler than Railroad but it is still a **great project**.

Answer (score 3):

Some IDE's have this feature, if I remember rightly RubyMine does.

Answer (score 2):

Rails ERD has excellent documentation and gallery:
http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/gallery.html