# RailRoad is not working. Giving me issues ie /railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb:54:in `disable_stdout': uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-schema

Here is various outputs

```
railroad -M | dot -Tsvg > models.svg
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb:54:in `disable_stdout': uninitialized constant AppDiagram::PLATFORM (NameError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb:72:in `load_environment'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb:18:in `initialize'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/models_diagram.rb:14:in `initialize'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/bin/railroad:36:in `new'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/bin/railroad:36:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/railroad:19:in `load'
from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/railroad:19:in `<main>'
```

Versions

```
me$ ruby -v
  ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.1.0]
me$ rvm -v
  rvm 1.8.0 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

me$ rails -v
  Rails 3.0.10
```

[Every command](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) is giving me same issue:

- railroad -o models.dot -M
- railroad -a -i -o full_models.dot -M
- railroad -M | dot -Tsvg > models.svg
- railroad -C | neato -Tpng > controllers.png

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Railroad is not working with ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.10. [Railroady](https://github.com/preston/railroady) is advanced maintained version..

Answer (score 3):

Edit /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railroad-0.5.0/lib/railroad/app_diagram.rb at line 54 and change PLATFORM to RUBY_PLATFORM.

See: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=26418&group_id=3383&atid=12998