# How can I install the Dot utility to Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dot

I am new to Ruby on Rails and i try to generate a UML-Graph with the Gem Railroady. Now i recieve the error message including Missing Dot. This is my Error Message

```
** Invoke diagram:all (first_time)
** Invoke diagram:setup:create_new_doc_folder_if_needed (first_time)
** Execute diagram:setup:create_new_doc_folder_if_needed
** Invoke diagram:models:complete (first_time)
** Execute diagram:models:complete
Generating C:/Sites/hausarbeit/diagramm/nanny_app/doc/models_complete.svg
railroady -lamM | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | dot -Tsvg > C:/Sites/hausarbeit/diagramm/nanny_app/doc/models_complete.svg
 Der Befehl "dot" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (255): [railroady -lamM | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1...]
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66:in `block in create_shell_runner'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:56:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:56:in `sh'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railroady-1.5.2/tasks/railroady.rake:64:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => diagram:all => diagram:models:complete
```

Now I´m pretty sure that I need to install this.

How can I do this? Sorry I´m very new to Rails.

Comment: whats the exact error you getting?

Comment: watch updated question.

Comment: You may want to translate this to english, if you can, ` Der Befehl "dot" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.`, as it appears to be the source of your problem, that said, not many people who can help you will know how to read german

Comment: After using google translate and googling, this appears to be the same question, try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098359/two-errors-when-using-railroad-for-rails

Comment: are you using Mac or Windows or Linux?

Comment: Where is dot installed (try `which dot`)? Check if `$PATH` environment variable contains directory with dot executable. Probably dot is incorrectly installed (did you use package mechanism for your linux distribution)?

Comment: This is windows, note the `C:/` paths.